# Layouts are not displayed in identical projects in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I just copied an Android Studio project into a new folder and want Android Studio to work on the new folder from now on. Unfortunately the layout files are not correctly displayed (I only see a grey layout without any elements) and I get the message that "This project does not use the Gradle build system". I do not undestand why this error occurs. I have not added or deleted anything from the original files and projects. I invalidated the cache and restarted but the problem still exists.

Does anyone have a clue what I have to do? I'd appreciate every comment.

Do you have an idea what the problem might be and what I have to do. I'd be quite thankful for your help as I do not know what to do.

Comment: Import the project with gradle, check in the File menu. You need to build the project in order to see the layout preview.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for your comment. How can I import the project with grandle? As written in the post, I have just copied and pasted a project folder in which everything was fine. So I do not understand why this problem occurs.

Comment: This might happen for various reasons. One simple reason which I encountered was when I opened the project in ```Android Studio``` at a directory/folder higher than the actual project directory/folder. As a result, **Android Studio** was not able detect the gradle files which were actually present but in the next folder level. You should check that you're opening the exact project folder and not any folder above it. This however, mostly happens when you download projects from ```Github``` that normally has many individual projects inside a folder.

Comment: Thanks Dev for your answer. This was exactly my problem. Now I could fix it because of your great advice. Thanks a lot (if you write your comment in an answer, I will upvote and accept it such that you get the deserved points).

Comment: Glad it worked :-)